# display number as image in sql

Tags: php, css, sql, database

I'm designing a website for a neighbor for a potential restaurant he wants to open. I need to create a page for testimonials/review. I'd like to code it so that the number of stars is in a SQL, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way to determine the integer of the ratings field (1-5) and for each number, display a star image.

So:

```
if rating = 1, display star.png once
if rating = 2, display star.png twice
...
if rating = 5, display star.png five times
```

I'm just not sure how to write the code to do so.

The website is being written in PHP and CSS. I'd like to avoid JQuery, Javascript, .NET, and so forth, as I'm not as familiar with them and will be the one keeping the site up to date.

Here's what I've got so far, but it's not working right, and I get a syntax error:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Reviews");   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
    IF (Rating = "1"()){
    echo '<img src="star.png">' . }
ELSE IF (Rating = "2"()){
    echo '<img src="star.png"><img src="images/star.png">' . }
Else IF (Rating = "3"()){
    echo '<img src="star.png">star.png"><img src="images/star.png">' . }
    ELSE IF (Rating = "4"()){
    echo '<img src="star.png"><img src="images/star.png">star.png"><img src="images/star.png">' . }
ELSE 
    echo '<img src="star.png"><img src="images/star.png">star.png"><img src="images/star.png"><img src="images/star.png">' .
"<br/> <b>" . 
$row['Name'] . 
"</b> <em>" . 
$row['City'] . $row['State'] . $row['Country'] . "</em><br/>" . 
$row['Review'] . "<br/> <hr> <br/>"
  }
?>
```

Comment: Try it yourself, and then show us what you've done.  We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Which part are you having difficult with? Setting up the db table, querying the db table, the php code, ...? If it is all of the above, your question is too broad for S.O. and may be closed. Can you narrow it down a little and show us what you have tried? [Ask]

Comment: Added my code to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help from a friend:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$starCount = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Reviews");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $starCount = $row['Rating'] ;
  while ($starCount > 0) {
    echo '<img src="images/star.png">';
    $starCount  -- ;
  }
  $starCount = 0;

  echo "<br/> <b>" . $row['Name'] . "</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<em>" . 
$row['City'] .",&nbsp;". $row['State'] ."&nbsp;". $row['Country'] . "</em><br/>" .
$row['Review'] . "<br/> <hr> <br/>" ;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select` statement to get the ratings for a place from your database.

Store the result in a php variable (lets call it `$rating`)

Use php logic to output number of stars (in html obviously) based on value of `$rating`.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 3 tables for this idea.

Users Table
UserRatings Table
Dish Table

Users table is used to store just that. User information. Possibly a username, password, first name, last name for example. The table should have a primary key. Call it UsersID. It should auto increment itself and be unique for every row.

The Dish table is next. Put a dish name in it. It should have a primary key as well. Call it DishID.

Lastly is the UserRatings table will store UserRatingsId, Rating, InsertTimeStamp, UpdateTimeStamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to output your HTML based on your rating.

```
$rating = 4;  //Figure this out in your script and set accordingly

for($i = 0; $i < $rating; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="star.png" />';
}
```

Should print out four stars for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $number=$row->rating   ;   
 $middle="";
 $first="<td width='200' align='left'>";
  for($x=1;$x<=$number;$x++) {

   $middle=$middle.img($fullimage_properties);  
}


if (strpos($number,'.')) {
    $middle=$middle.img($halfimage_properties); 
    $x++;
}
while ($x<=5) {
    $middle=$middle.img($blankimage_properties);    ;
    $x++;
}


echo $last=$first.$middle."</td>";
```